# pgRouting problem

Tags: pgrouting

I have an issue with a PostgreSQL/pgRouting query. I have two subqueries, each finding a point for the origin or destination using long lat pulled from a couple other tables.

What's confusing me is that both subqueries work perfectly fine when executed individually. However, when I include them together in the same query, only the first one seems to work, and the second one seems to not have any effect.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is the query in full:

```
SELECT r.seq, r.node, w.name AS street, r.cost::numeric(10, 4),

SUM(w.length_m)::numeric(10, 2) AS total_length,

ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(w.the_geom ORDER BY r.seq)) AS route_geometry

FROM pgr_dijkstra(

'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, the_geom, cost, reverse_cost FROM public.ways',



(SELECT id FROM public.ways_vertices_pgr

ORDER BY the_geom <->

(SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(fire_incident.long, fire_incident.lat), 4326)

FROM fire_incident WHERE fire_id = 'fire_00001') LIMIT 1),



(SELECT id FROM public.ways_vertices_pgr

ORDER BY the_geom <->

(SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(fire_stations.long, fire_stations.lat), 4326)

FROM fire_stations WHERE station_id = 'stat_01') LIMIT 1),

true) AS r



LEFT JOIN public.ways AS w ON r.edge = w.gid

GROUP BY r.seq, r.node, w.name, r.cost

ORDER BY r.seq;
```